# If I have given the word ssseeerabbcccdd then output should be like s3e3rab2c3d2 in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Word : "); 
        string word = Console.ReadLine(); 
        for (var i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            var check = true; 
            var count = 0; 
            for (var k = i - 1; k <= 0; k--) 
            { 
                if (word[k] == word[i]) check = false; 
            } 
            if (check)
            { 
                for (var j = i; j<= word.Length; j++)
                { 
                    if (word[i] == word[j]) count++; 
                } 
                Console.WriteLine(word[i] + " Occurs at " + count + " places.");

            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have tried this one but not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `check` is set to `false` if the string contains two adjacent identical characters. So `if (check) {...}` won't be executed, if this is the case. Another problem is that you set `k` to string position `-1` in the first iteration of `for (var k = i - 1; k <= 0; k--)`. If `i=0`, then k will be `-1`. You also need only one inner loop.

Here is a possible solution, although slightly different than your's.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Word : "); 
        string word = Console.ReadLine();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < word.Length) 
        {
            int count = 1;
            for (int k = i+1; k < word.Length; k++)
                if (word[i] == word[k])
                    count++;
            if (count>1)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(word[i] + " Occurs at " + count + " places.");
            }
            i += count;   // continue next char or after after repeated chars
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```